# dockerfile - adding dependencies - libjpeg error

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, libjpeg

Im trying to dockerize a nodejs project that uses the `chartjs-node module` for creating png images from the `chartjs` graphs.

It has some requirements that I've added to my `dockerfile`

full docker file :

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
apt-utils \
libcairo2-dev \
libjpeg-dev \
libpango1.0-dev \
libgif-dev \
build-essential \
g++

WORKDIR /graphService

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -y

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

but on `docker logs` i get this error from my app:

**Unhandled rejection Error: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

It's working outside docker container if i just normally npm start it in my linux 16:04 env.

Comment: Did you try this fix, https://github.com/OpenGeoscience/geonotebook/issues/159

Comment: yes, also tried adding libjpeg-turbo8 and other versions with same results, also tried it on the ubuntu:16.04 image without luck.